# Keyboard module gives overflow error when converting script to exe

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I was trying to create a program to record keyboard keys using the keyboard module of Python.
I want to create a standalone executable file for the program. So I used PyInstaller as well as other *py to exe converters* to convert my script to exe format but it always gives an Overflow Error on execution.

```html
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "threading.py", line 864, in run
  File "site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 292, in listen
  File "site-packages\keyboard\_winkeyboard.py", line 560, in listen
  File "site-packages\keyboard\_winkeyboard.py", line 553, in prepare_intercept
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'OverflowError'>: int too long to convert
```

What can I do to prevent it?
Or is there any other way to create a standalone file to run a python script on other computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in the way the keyboard module imports the SetWindowsHookEx Windows API (ctypes defaults all params to int and SetWindowsHookEx's third param is a HINSTANCE, which on 64 bits is 64 bits wide). The (hackish) solution is to patch the library - add `c_longlong` to the imports from `ctypes` on line 32 of `_winkeyboard.py`, then uncomment the argtypes for SetWindowsHookEx on line 95 and change the third to c_longlong:
`SetWindowsHookEx.argtypes = [c_int, LowLevelKeyboardProc, c_longlong, c_int]`